# Wicket modalwindow returning value

Tags: forms, dialog, wicket, return-value, modal-window

I want to create a settings-dialog in my wicket page. I created a ModalWindow that contains a form to achieve this. This works great, the dialog shows up and it contains the form but now I need to return some of these values in the form back to the caller page. Is there someone who could give me pointers on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [ModalWindow API](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/modal/ModalWindow.html):

> "If you want to use form in modal window component make sure that you
>   put the modal window itself in another form (nesting forms is legal in
>   Wicket) and that the form on modal window is submitted before the
>   window get closed"

This way when you submit the form in the modal window actually the parent form gets submitted and you get the values transferred.